# ./configure doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, make, configure, autoconf

In order to install programs on Ubuntu, I keep seeing these instructions:

```
tar -xzf archive-name.tar.gz
cd archive-name
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

However, this is always the result (terminal and the folder on my screen):

[image: My Screenshot]

Obviously, I did something wrong. Can anyone tell me what? [This is the software I'm trying to install](https://launchpad.net/parcel-tracker).

I mixed a couple of suggestions together, and none worked. Below is the result:
[image]

Comment: Can you do `ls` and paste the output in your question?

Comment: jonesy@jonesy-K53E:~/Downloads/parcel-tracker$ ls

AUTHORS  data    parcel_tracker             po

bin      debian  parcel-tracker.desktop.in  setup.py

COPYING  help    parcel_tracker_lib         tests

Comment: Sorry. Tried to space it out...didn't quite work...

Comment: why don't you read the help file?
EDIT: I mean post

Comment: that did not work either

Tried it with both underscore and dash
jonesy@jonesy-K53E:~/Downloads/parcel-tracker$ parcel_tracker/configure
bash: parcel_tracker/configure: No such file or directory
jonesy@jonesy-K53E:~/Downloads/parcel-tracker$ parcel-tracker/configure
bash: parcel-tracker/configure: No such file or directory


I don't know how to post a picture in the comments.

Comment: You should edit the original question with updates and simply comment and @mention the user that made the suggestions.

Comment: I see a `setup.py` file listed there. What if you run that (`./setup.py`)?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I tried that, and as I edited above, still didn't work. Unless I did it wrong...

Comment: @user3272527 you're already in the `parcel-tracker` directory. I see there is another `parcel-tracker` directory inside that one, but `setup.py` is just inside the one you're in right now. Try running `./setup.py`.

Comment: Sorry @Zacharee1, the damn terminal keeps spitting No such file or directory at me!

I cannot understand why I'm following instructions to the letter, but getting no results.

Comment: What command are you running? You should make sure that the setup file is executable: `sudo chmod +x ~/Downloads/parcel-tracker/setup.py`. Then run `~/Downloads/parcel-tracker/setup.py`. I'm going to use paths that a re slightly less relative so that I know you're running the right thing.

Comment: Don't give up just yet! Try what I suggested first.

Comment: I've added an answer, which I believe will solve your problem: by avoiding it completely.

Comment: The usual way to run Python setup.py files is `[sudo] python setup.py install`, but use @Zacharee1's answer now.

Comment: @grooveplex oh, that's how you do it :p

Answer (score 6):

I kind of hate to tell you this, since you've done so much work and all, but that's a Launchpad page and it has a PPA. A PPA is sort of an index of packages Ubuntu can use to download and install what is requested. If you add that PPA, you can just install `parcel-tracker` with a simple command in the terminal.

Run the below commands to install `parcel-tracker`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:torkvemada/torkvemada
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install parcel-tracker
```

Confirm any prompts you get.

I think that's it. The package does have a version for Ubuntu 16.04, so I don't think you'll run into any errors.

Answer (score 0):

As an oversimplification, the configure script and make have been typically shipped with C/C++ or Fortan source code .  configure scripts are generally used to setup compile options and ensure that dependencies are present.  automake is typically used to compile the code and install the binaries in system locations.

hence, if you download source code for an application and the developer uses configure and make to build the application, then you will need to do the same.  sometimes, applications are distributed as binaries (precompiled).  those won't ship with configure and make.  also, java applications typically don't use configure and make.  so it depends on the build tools that the developer chose when they wrote the application.

Comment: If it didn't come with configure and make, then how do you install it?

I thought that was the purpose of those...

Comment: some don't come with "install" scripts/tools. you can just run them from wherever you extract the archive or you can move it yourself to the system location you deem appropriate. e.g. /opt

Comment: I did, in fact, use /opt, My messgenger for desktop was there. Once there, how do I access the program?

Answer (score 0):

Execute

```
autoreconf -vfi
```

inside your extracted source root directory. This will generate a `configure` file specific to your system, that you can execute afterwards. Make sure it is executable for you, e. g.:

```
chmod u+x configure
```

then

```
./configure
```

should work.

Answer (score -1):

Not all tar archives have ./configure files. I wanted to install Eclipse a while ago and it doesn't have one. I instead ran an alternate windows version through wine (though this is not preferable, it worked). Do a little research on the software and see if it does have a configure file. Sometimes it could be called ./config.